# Notation for intersection between simple polygons

Tags: notation

Imagine you have two simple polygons A and B in two-dimensional space. I say that A is a polygon represented by a set of ordered vertices (same story with B). I want to say that A and B do not intersect (or, in other words, they do not overlap). Does the following notation express the idea that A and B do not intersect?

$A\cap B=\emptyset$

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the correct notation.